# Existence of bounded, continuous decreasing net with pointwise limit on completely regular space

Tags: functional-analysis, nets

I'm reading a paper (""A simple proof in Monge-Kantorovich duality theory" by D. A. Edwards), in which the following Lemma is proved. I understand the Lemma and its proof, but not the author's conclusion. Maybe someone can help?

Lemma: Let $Z$ be a completely regular space, $h: Z \to [-\infty, \infty)$ upper semicontinuous with $h\leq0$, $z_0 \in Z$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(z_0)<t$. Then there exists $g \in \mathcal{C}_b(Z)$ such that $h\leq g\leq0$ and $g(z_0)<t$.

The proof basically only uses the completely regular property and the fact that $h\leq 0$.

The author claims: "From this Lemma it follows immediately that there exists a decreasing net $(h_\alpha)$ in $\mathcal{C}_b(Z)$ (real-valued, bounded, continuous functions) that has pointwise limit $h$ and is such that $h_\alpha \leq 0 ~ \forall \alpha$."

By taking $\alpha=t$ I would understand how to construct a net converging at one point $z_0$. But how does it converge pointwise, i.e. for all $z \in Z$, and how is this net decreasing, i.e. $h_{\alpha_1} \geq h_{\alpha_2}$ for $\alpha_2 > \alpha_1$?

Comment: Take $\alpha = (F, (t_1, \dotsc, t_k))$ where $F \subseteq Z$ has $k$ elements $z_1, \dotsc, z_k$, and $h(z_i) \leqslant t_i \leqslant 0$.

Comment: About the Lemma: Isn't $g=0$ always a possible choice? This would make the Lemma that you want to use very simple.

Comment: @supinf: Sorry, there was a typo. It's supposed to read $g(z_0) < t$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't quite understand. You mean to take $h_\alpha$ to be such that $h_\alpha(z_i)<t_i$ for $i=1, ..., n$? According to the Lemma I'm allowed to constrain the function $h_\alpha$ at one point $z_0$, not at multiple ones at the same time? And it still might not ensure the decreasing property on all of $Z$ I think?

Comment: If you have $g_1$ for $z_1, t_1$ and $g_2$ for $z_2, t_2$, what do you get from $\min \{g_1, g_2\}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot, that was a great help!